# keystone.js limit of fields, types to 21

Tags: keystonejs

Created a form with keystone.js where user can enter values and save, which I am saving as an array in the database, but after 21(0-20) entry is not letting the user enter more values or is not saving to the database. Is there any basic limitation in keystone what I need to change in the fields?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as suggested when you signed up today, to get a better idea of what types of questions you can ask. This question is too broad and lacks any substantial information for users to work on. Please add your code, attempt and error message.

Comment: Can you post your database model code? It should be in `models` directory.